# Controlling the Zoom out view port in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am trying out the examples given [here](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-5#pan_zoom) on the pan and zoom in fabric js and got it working. I am using the zoom to point to zoom where the cursor was. However, the problem I face is that if I zoomIn in one place and zoomOut in another, there is an offset created between the border and background. Even though the code works for restricting the pan area to 1000x400 px, while zooming out, the boundaries are not restricted.

How can I restrict the boundaries even while zooming out, such that there is no offset?

Code here:

```js
(function(){
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1',{backgroundImage:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520299607509-dcd935f9a839?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1489&q=80"});
 viewportTransform=canvas.viewportTransform;
    canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ width: 50, height: 50, fill: 'blue', angle: 10 }))
    canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 50, fill: 'red', top: 44, left: 80 }))
    canvas.add(new fabric.Ellipse({ rx: 50, ry: 10, fill: 'yellow', top: 80, left: 35 }))
    canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ width: 50, height: 50, fill: 'purple', angle: -19, top: 70, left: 70 }))
    canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 50, fill: 'green', top: 110, left: 30 }))
    canvas.add(new fabric.Ellipse({ rx: 50, ry: 10, fill: 'orange', top: 12, left: 100, angle: 30 }))
    canvas.on('mouse:wheel', (opt) => {
      var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
      var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
      zoom *= 0.999 ** delta;
      if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
      if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
      canvas.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(opt.e.offsetX, opt.e.offsetY), zoom);
      opt.e.preventDefault();
      opt.e.stopPropagation();
      var vpt = viewportTransform;
      if (zoom < 0.4) {
        vpt[4] = 200 - 1000 * zoom / 2;
        vpt[5] = 200 - 400 * zoom / 2;
      } else {
        if (vpt[4] >= 0) {
          vpt[4] = 0;
        } else if (vpt[4] < canvas.getWidth() - 1000 * zoom) {
          vpt[4] = canvas.getWidth() - 1000 * zoom;
        }
        if (vpt[5] >= 0) {
          vpt[5] = 0;
        } else if (vpt[5] < canvas.getHeight() - 400 * zoom) {
          vpt[5] = canvas.getHeight() - 400 * zoom;
        }
      }
    });
    canvas.on('mouse:down', function (opt) {
      var evt= opt.e;
      if (evt.altKey === true) {
        this.isDragging = true;
        this.selection = false;
        this.lastPosX = evt.clientX;
        this.lastPosY = evt.clientY;
      }
    });
    canvas.on('mouse:move', function (opt) {
      if (this.isDragging) {
        var e = opt.e;
        var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
        var vpt = this.viewportTransform;
        if (zoom < 0.4) {
          vpt[4] = 200 - 1000 * zoom / 2;
          vpt[5] = 200 - 400 * zoom / 2;
        } else {
          vpt[4] += e.clientX - this.lastPosX;
          vpt[5] += e.clientY - this.lastPosY;
          if (vpt[4] >= 0) {
            vpt[4] = 0;
          } else if (vpt[4] < canvas.getWidth() - 1000 * zoom) {
            vpt[4] = canvas.getWidth() - 1000 * zoom;
          }
          if (vpt[5] >= 0) {
            vpt[5] = 0;
          } else if (vpt[5] < canvas.getHeight() - 400 * zoom) {
            vpt[5] = canvas.getHeight() - 400 * zoom;
          }
        }
        this.requestRenderAll();
        this.lastPosX = e.clientX;
        this.lastPosY = e.clientY;
      }
    });
    canvas.on('mouse:up', function (opt) {
      this.setViewportTransform(this.viewportTransform);
      this.isDragging = false;
      this.selection = true;
    });
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
  <canvas id="canvas1" height="300" width="400" style="border:1px solid"></canvas>
```

Issue Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with the `mouse:wheel` handler:

- you are updating an incorrect viewportTransform object
- you are not rendering the canvas after updating the viewportTransform

Change the handler from:

```
canvas.on('mouse:wheel', (opt) => {
      ...
      var vpt = viewportTransform;
      ...
    });
```

to

```
canvas.on('mouse:wheel', (opt) => {
      ...
      var vpt = canvas.viewportTransform;
      ...
      canvas.requestRenderAll();
    });
```

Full code:

```js
(function(){
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1',{backgroundImage:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520299607509-dcd935f9a839?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1489&q=80"});
 viewportTransform=canvas.viewportTransform;
    canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ width: 50, height: 50, fill: 'blue', angle: 10 }))
    canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 50, fill: 'red', top: 44, left: 80 }))
    canvas.add(new fabric.Ellipse({ rx: 50, ry: 10, fill: 'yellow', top: 80, left: 35 }))
    canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ width: 50, height: 50, fill: 'purple', angle: -19, top: 70, left: 70 }))
    canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 50, fill: 'green', top: 110, left: 30 }))
    canvas.add(new fabric.Ellipse({ rx: 50, ry: 10, fill: 'orange', top: 12, left: 100, angle: 30 }))
    canvas.on('mouse:wheel', (opt) => {
      var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
      var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
      zoom *= 0.999 ** delta;
      if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
      if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
      canvas.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(opt.e.offsetX, opt.e.offsetY), zoom);
      opt.e.preventDefault();
      opt.e.stopPropagation();
      var vpt = canvas.viewportTransform;
      if (zoom < 0.4) {
        vpt[4] = 200 - 1000 * zoom / 2;
        vpt[5] = 200 - 400 * zoom / 2;
      } else {
        if (vpt[4] >= 0) {
          vpt[4] = 0;
        } else if (vpt[4] < canvas.getWidth() - 1000 * zoom) {
          vpt[4] = canvas.getWidth() - 1000 * zoom;
        }
        if (vpt[5] >= 0) {
          vpt[5] = 0;
        } else if (vpt[5] < canvas.getHeight() - 400 * zoom) {
          vpt[5] = canvas.getHeight() - 400 * zoom;
        }
      }
      canvas.requestRenderAll();
    });
    canvas.on('mouse:down', function (opt) {
      var evt= opt.e;
      if (evt.altKey === true) {
        this.isDragging = true;
        this.selection = false;
        this.lastPosX = evt.clientX;
        this.lastPosY = evt.clientY;
      }
    });
    canvas.on('mouse:move', function (opt) {
      if (this.isDragging) {
        var e = opt.e;
        var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
        var vpt = this.viewportTransform;
        if (zoom < 0.4) {
          vpt[4] = 200 - 1000 * zoom / 2;
          vpt[5] = 200 - 400 * zoom / 2;
        } else {
          vpt[4] += e.clientX - this.lastPosX;
          vpt[5] += e.clientY - this.lastPosY;
          if (vpt[4] >= 0) {
            vpt[4] = 0;
          } else if (vpt[4] < canvas.getWidth() - 1000 * zoom) {
            vpt[4] = canvas.getWidth() - 1000 * zoom;
          }
          if (vpt[5] >= 0) {
            vpt[5] = 0;
          } else if (vpt[5] < canvas.getHeight() - 400 * zoom) {
            vpt[5] = canvas.getHeight() - 400 * zoom;
          }
        }
        this.requestRenderAll();
        this.lastPosX = e.clientX;
        this.lastPosY = e.clientY;
      }
    });
    canvas.on('mouse:up', function (opt) {
      this.setViewportTransform(this.viewportTransform);
      this.isDragging = false;
      this.selection = true;
    });
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
  <canvas id="canvas1" height="300" width="400" style="border:1px solid"></canvas>
```

Comment: viewportTransform is already set of canvas.viewportTransform in line 2. Also, I am not facing any issue in zoom in, zoom out or panning. The issue is when I zoomOut, how do I ensure that there is no offset. The zoom out should stop where the offset begins

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a full code snippet. You can see that it behaves differently when zooming out.
And yes, `viewportTransform` is set on line 2. But when the code inside `mouse:wheel` handler is executing, the `canvas` is already using a different viewportTransform object and you need to work with the new one.

Comment: thanks. One question. What does 200 - 1000 * zoom / 2; mean? 1000 is the width of the BG image I beleive, but not sure of the rest of the line. Can you add some explanation of the code ( maybe comments?) so that in future more will find it useful

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, as that code was copied from your question directly. 
But if i were to guess, it serves to center the image when it is zoomed out too much.
That line of code is located inside an `if(zoom < 0.4) {...}`. That means that it only comes into play when the image dimension is less than 400px wide (0.4*1000), which is exactly the size of the area, in which the image is displayed.